# Store value in a variable in jinja template for later use

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

Hello please give a solution to my problem:
I want to store a value to a variable by the below method but unable to do that

```
{% if tags %}
{% for t in tags %}
{% if t.job_post_one != "hide" %}
"Store the value of t.job_post_one here "`
```

later use that value at the end of the html for filtering results based on that value.

Comment: You don't this is *business logic*, so you should implement that in the view. It will likely be faster and more elegant as well.

Comment: how to implement in view can you please give an example. Actually i am creating one blog and in the sidebar i want to display list of related posts from the present blog category